# Connection to prod APNs with development cert

Tags: ios, ruby, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I'm using this Ruby code to receive errors from APNs on unsuccessful pushes:

```
if IO.select([ssl], nil, nil, 5)
    read_buffer = ssl.read(6)
    process_error_response(read_buffer)
end
```

I noticed a weird situation where IO.select is non-nil but read_buffer returns an empty string. After some debugging I realized that this happens if you connect to gateway.push.apple.com with a development APNs cert, and the same thing apparently happens if you connect to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com with a production cert.

Is there any way to programmatically detect that this is the case, e.g. if you're given a push certificate by a user and told it's production/development but can't actually verify that fact on the Apple developer site? I would have thought that the connection would be rejected, but instead it seems to be created but in a partly-broken state.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not a way to check if the cert is APNS valid, but you can inspect it if you want to detect whether it is a development or production one. The development will have the "Developer" string in it, whereas the production will have the "Production" string.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to open the certificate and check the subject, example:

```
require 'openssl'
def production?(cert_path)
  certificate = ::OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read(cert_path))
  !certificate.subject.to_s.include?('Development')
end
```

For production certificates the subject looks like:

```
"Apple Production IOS Push Services: com.mybundle.app..."
```

For development certificates looks like:

```
"Apple Development IOS Push Services: com.mybundle.app..."
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used the cert to to send it to myself from [command line directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65270300/5175709)...

When using a development cert I see:

```
api.development.push.apple.com
```

I'm not testing with a production cert, but I'm pretty sure when you send it with production then instead of the above you'll see:

```
api.push.apple.com
```

FWIW a *production* cert will work in a *development* (app *not* signed with distribution cert) environments — as long as both environments have the same bundleId. However a production cert won't work in production environment (app signed with distribution cert)

Aside from that the more secured way nowadays is to not user certificates and instead just use a *key/token* mechanism. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_token-based_connection_to_apns)