# cURL with a PKCS#12 certificate in a bash script

Tags: bash, curl, openssl, pkcs#12

i have to connect to a webservice, where a pkcs12 certificate is a must. the idea was to use curl in a bash script (under OS X, to be specific).

i have learnt that one of the few things curl cannot do in communication, is handling pkcs12 certificates (.p12). what are my options?

i have read that converting the certificate to PEM format would work (using openssl), however i have no idea how to tell curl that it gets a PEM and should communicate with a webservice requesting PKCS12 certificates.

converting pkcs12 to pem would be done like this (e.g.), it worked for me, however i haven't successfully used them with curl:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.p12 -out file.key.pem -nocerts -nodes
openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.p12 -out file.crt.pem -clcerts -nokeys
```

any hints? or, any alternatives to curl? the solution should be commandline based.

Answer (score 100):

I think you have already resolved but I had the same problem. I answer to share my solution.

If you have a .p12 file your approach is right.
First of all, you have to get the cert and the key separated from the p12 file.
As an example, if you have a `mycert.p12` file execute

```
openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.p12 -out file.key.pem -nocerts -nodes
openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.p12 -out file.crt.pem -clcerts -nokeys
```

Then you have to make the call to your url. For instance, assume that you want to get the WSDL of a specific web service

```
curl -E ./file.crt.pem --key ./file.key.pem https://myservice.com/service?wsdl
```

If the files `file.crt.pem` and `file.key.pem` are in your working folder "./" is mandatory.

Comment: For me this worked:

curl -k --cert ./file.crt.pem --cert-type PEM --key ./file.key.pem --key-type PEM --pass <ImportPassword> "<HTTPS_URL>"

Comment: Just letting people know here that if you use `curl -k` as Kartins used in the comment above, you are **disabling** https checks.

Comment: also, using `-nodes` disables encryption which means you are taking your private key out of a password-protected encrypted file and storing it as an unprotected, unencrypted file; some versions of curl support encrypted PEM files, so `-nodes` may not even be necessary

Answer (score 86):

Check if you have a newer curl. Newer versions can handle PKCS12 outright.

Tangentially, quote the password, or individually escape all shell metacharacters.

```
curl --cert-type P12 --cert cert.p12:'password' https://yoursite.com
```

Comment: you may have to add "--insecure"
curl --insecure --cert-type P12 --cert cert.p12:password https://yoursite.com

Comment: @mancocapac it kinda defeats the purpose of secure connectivity

Comment: you are correct, however in my case it was required. Working for company X, they have a cert and use it internally, its not registered with CA. without this flag i can't use curl nor postman.

Comment: @mancocapac Using --insecure is not required. When using a private CA, use the private CA's private CA certificate, not --insecure.

Comment: @mancocapac, thanks with --insecure it worked fro me

Comment: People are confusing your identify, ie. saying who you are to the server (using a client certificate via the `cert` argument) and trusting the server is who it says it is.   The `insecure` argument is about trust and the correct solution here is to use the `cacert` argument pointing at the root (and possibly intermediate) CA certificates for the server.   Simply adding `insecure` or `k` is completely defeating the whole point of TLS as you are just bypassing it

Comment: @bioffe - do you know what version this was added by chance?

Comment: See for example this commit in curl repo : https://github.com/curl/curl/commit/a8324599d236930208510faf7ccaef91214e69fc

Answer (score 6):

[bioffe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55890905/5175709)s answer is correct.

He was suggesting to do:

```
curl --cert-type P12 --cert cert.p12:password https://yoursite.com
```

For some reason that didn't work for me. I was getting:

> curl could not open PKCS12 file

I just ended up exporting the `p12` file **without** a password and then used the following format:

```
curl --cert-type P12 --cert cert.p12 https://yoursite.com
```

You can easily check to see if your `curl` can handle `p12`. Very likely it does. Just do `man curl` and search for the option by typing `/cert-type`<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Here's what the manual says for me:

> `--cert-type <type>`
>
> (TLS) Tells curl what type the provided client certificate is using. PEM, DER, ENG and P12 are recognized types. If not specified, PEM is assumed.
>
> If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.

Comment: first command with password works as long as the password is correct else you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excerpt from the curl manpage:

> **--cert-type**
>
> (TLS) Tells curl what type the provided client certificate is using.
> PEM, DER, ENG and P12 are recog‐ nized types. If not specified, PEM is
> assumed.
>
> If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.
>
> See also -E, --cert and --key and --key-type.
>
> **-E, --cert <certificate[:password]>**
>
> (TLS) Tells curl to use the specified client certificate file when
> getting a file with HTTPS, FTPS or another SSL-based protocol. The
> certificate must be in PKCS#12 format if using Secure Transport, or
> PEM format if using any other engine. If the optional password isn't
> specified, it will be queried for on the terminal. Note that this
> option assumes a "certificate" file that is the private key and the
> client certificate concatenated! See -E, --cert and --key to specify
> them independently.
>
> If curl is built against the NSS SSL library then this option can tell
> curl the nickname of the certificate to use within the NSS database
> defined by the environment variable SSL_DIR (or by default
> /etc/pki/nssdb). If the NSS PEM PKCS#11 module (libnsspem.so) is
> available then PEM files may be loaded. If you want to use a file from
> the current directory, please precede it with "./" prefix, in order to
> avoid confusion with a nickname. If the nickname contains ":", it
> needs to be preceded by "\" so that it is not recognized as password
> delimiter. If the nickname contains "\", it needs to be escaped as
> "\\" so that it is not recognized as an escape character.