# Using a .p12 file/certificate to make a curl call

Tags: curl, certificate, ssl-certificate

Having issues making a curl call on mac terminal (also tried in linux) using a .p12 file/certificate.

This works when adding to my "keychain" and sending this using a Rest client like postman. Is it possible these two systems are conflicting? What do I have to do to make this work in other environments as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you have to extract the certificate and key from your .p12 file first and then provide it in the curl command something like this:

```
curl --key client.key --cert client.crt -X GET -v https://httpbin.org/get
```

Comment: This SO question/answer shows how to extract  the keys from a PKCS#12 file for use with curl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253909/curl-with-a-pkcs12-certificate-in-a-bash-script