# Unable to create .pem file from .p12 (private key + public key)

Tags: ios, openssl, cryptography, certificate

I am trying to create `.pem` file from `.p12` file with below command,

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in Certificates.p12 -out Certificates.pem
```

But getting below error:

```
4412094060:error:0DFFF0A8:asn1 encoding routines:CRYPTO_internal:wrong tag:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.260.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1125:
4412094060:error:0DFFF03A:asn1 encoding routines:CRYPTO_internal:nested asn1 error:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.260.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:306:Type=X509_CINF
4412094060:error:0DFFF03A:asn1 encoding routines:CRYPTO_internal:nested asn1 error:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.260.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:627:Field=cert_info, Type=X509
```

**Any idea how to resolve it?**

Comment: Have you tried creating new certificate?

Comment: Yes already updated `.p12`

Comment: Can you revoke your certificate and create new certificate and try if this works.

Comment: @Daljeet my certificate is already latest and working fine with all other system, i.e. Knuff tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below command worked fine,

```
openssl pkcs12 -in Certificates.p12 -out Certificates.pem -nodes -clcerts
```