# curl with .p12 certificate in bash script

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl

I am trying to connect a secured webservice using curl command.
I have .p12 certificate,I generated key and certificate using

openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.p12 -out file.key.pem -nocerts -nodes

openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.p12 -out file.crt.pem -clcerts -nokeys

and then used curl command like :

curl -E ./file.crt.pem:password --key ./file.key.pem https://myservice.com/service?wsdl

But I am getting below error:

curl: (58) Unable to load client key -8178.

Certificate has password

I followed [cURL with a PKCS#12 certificate in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253909/curl-with-a-pkcs12-certificate-in-a-bash-script)